# Python :function that takes an iterable argument and generates tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

I try to do something on python.

I try to write a function that takes an iterable argument and generates tuples of 2 elements:

1. the current iterable element
2. the number of times it has been generated since the beginning

Here is my code

```
liste = ['a','b','a','a','b']

compte = {}.fromkeys(set(liste),0)
for valeur in liste:
     compte[valeur] += 1

print(compte)
```

output :

```
{'b': 2, 'a': 3}
```

But I want to obtain `"a:1" "b:1" "a:2" "a:3" and "b:2"`

Thanks for help

Comment: You cannot have a dictionary with identical keys. Maybe a list is what you are looking for? Seems like order is important in the result.

Comment: Also note that calling fromkeys on an *instance* of dict creates that instance pointlessly; it's a class method.

Answer (score 3):

Your expected result is a list, not a dictionary. A fix to your code would be to use your dict for counting, but appending to a list:

```
>>> liste = ['a','b','a','a','b']
>>>
>>> compte = dict.fromkeys(liste,0) #Or use a default dict
>>> result = []
>>> for valeur in liste:
...  compte[valeur] += 1
...  result.append((valeur,compte[valeur]))
...
>>> print(result)
[('a', 1), ('b', 1), ('a', 2), ('a', 3), ('b', 2)]
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a generator function.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def with_running_count(values):
    counts = defaultdict(int)
    for value in values:
        counts[value] += 1
        yield value, counts[value]

>>> print(*with_running_count('abaab'))

('a', 1) ('b', 1) ('a', 2) ('a', 3) ('b', 2)
```

One advantage of using a generator over the other suggestions is that generators are lazy. That means that you can pass in iterators that return an endless (or very large) data stream, since the generator only consumes the input stream when needed.

```
# an endless iterator
coin = iter(lambda: random.choice(['heads', 'tails']), None)

# the running count will also be endless        
toss = with_running_count(coin)

>>> next(toss), next(toss), next(toss)
(('tails', 1), ('tails', 2), ('heads', 1))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just modify your code in this way:

```py
liste = ['a','b','a','a','b']

liste2 = []
compte = {}.fromkeys(set(liste),0)
for valeur in liste:
    compte[valeur] += 1
    liste2.append(valeur + ':' + str(compte[valeur]))

print(liste2)
```

It is important to say: what you are trying to do it is not a tuple, but a list, because it is mutable. Your `compte` variable is a `dictionary`.

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize the dictionary with counts as you go:

```
liste = ['a','b','a','a','b']
compte = {}
result = []
for valeur in liste:
    compte[valeur] = compte.get(valeur, 0) + 1
    result.append((valeur, compte[valeur]))

print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Counter` from `collections` module:

```
from collections import Counter

liste = ['a','b','a','a','b']

def counter(iterable):
    c = Counter()
    for i in iterable:
        c.update(i)
        yield i, c[i]

print(list(counter(liste)))
```

Outputs:

```
[('a', 1), ('b', 1), ('a', 2), ('a', 3), ('b', 2)]
```